# Program exit is reached in IAR RL78 V2.20

Tags: c++, runtime-error, iar

I am working with YRDKRL78 G13 board. I am using IAR v.2.20 for compiler and ı have created a C++ project on it. And I am using one framework. Anyway I have implemented all my codes and which is working correctly but after 2 minutes IAR is giving information as "The Application is aborted" and "Program exit is reached." I am really confuse about it I used very large stack as 512 and near is 1024 far is the 4096.

Here is my main.cpp

```
#include "System.h"
extern "C"

{
#include "r_cg_macrodriver.h"
}

#pragma location = "OPTBYTE"
__root const uint8_t opbyte0 = 0x7EU;
#pragma location = "OPTBYTE"
__root const uint8_t opbyte1 = 0xFFU;
#pragma location = "OPTBYTE"
__root const uint8_t opbyte2 = 0xE8U;
#pragma location = "OPTBYTE"
__root const uint8_t opbyte3 = 0x85U;

/* Set security ID */
#pragma location = "SECUID"
__root const uint8_t secuid[10] =
{0x00U, 0x00U, 0x00U, 0x00U, 0x00U, 0x00U, 0x00U, 0x00U, 0x00U, 0x00U};

void main(void)
{

System::SystemInstance().SYS_vInit();
System::SystemInstance().SYS_vStart();
System::SystemInstance().SYS_vRun();

while(1)
{
;
}


}
```

And here is the iar output. [IAR Output Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1epi.png)

If somebody faced like this problem or if somebody has got any solution or idea could you please share with me here

Thanks for the help :)

EDIT:
@rjp Firstly thanks for response. I am using special framework on my board which Quantum leaps. these 3 functions are calling framwork functions and SYS_vRUN is calling endless loop

```
int_t QF::run(void) {
onStartup(); // startup callback

// the combined event-loop and background-loop of the QV kernel
for (;;) {
    R_WDT_Restart();
    RepaintLCD();
    delay_ms(50); /* Leave some room for the system to respond */
    QF_INT_DISABLE();
    if (QV_readySet_.notEmpty()) {
        uint_fast8_t p = QV_readySet_.findMax();
        QMActive *a = active_[p];
        QF_INT_ENABLE();

        // perform the run-to-completion (RTS) step...
        // 1. retrieve the event from the AO's event queue, which by this
        //    time must be non-empty and The "Vanialla" kernel asserts it.
        // 2. dispatch the event to the AO's state machine.
        // 3. determine if event is garbage and collect it if so
        //
        QEvt const *e = a->get_();
        a->dispatch(e);
        gc(e);
    }
    else {
        // QV::onIdle() must be called with interrupts DISABLED because
        // the determination of the idle condition (no events in the
        // queues) can change at any time by an interrupt posting events
        // to a queue. QV::onIdle() MUST enable interrupts internally,
        // perhaps at the same time as putting the CPU into a power-saving
        // mode.
        QP::QV::onIdle();
    }
}
}
```

End I searched all code for exit() function there is no any. But you mentioned another issue about assertion. here you can see assertion macro and custome implemented assertion function.

```
    #define Q_ASSERT_ID(id_, test_) ((test_) \
    ? (void)0 : Q_onAssert(&Q_this_module_[0], (int_t)(id_)))
```

Function;

```
    void Q_onAssert(char const Q_ROM * const file, int line) {
// implement the error-handling policy for your application!!!
QF_INT_DISABLE(); // disable all interrupts

// cause the reset of the CPU...
//WDTCTL = WDTPW | WDTHOLD;
//__asm("    push &0xFFFE");
// return from function does the reset
}
```

EDIT2:
Most dynamic memory processes are done in the LedFactory Class.
Header

```
/*
 * LedFactory.h
 *
 *  Created on: Aug 3, 2016
 *      Author: Dev
 */

 #ifndef APPLICATION_LED_LEDFACTORY_H_
 #define APPLICATION_LED_LEDFACTORY_H_

 #include "LedController.h"
 class LedFactory {
 public:
   typedef enum{
    LED1,
    LED2,
    LED3,
    LED4,
    LED5,
    LED6,
}LedTypes;
public:
LedFactory();
virtual ~LedFactory();
LedController * FirstLedFactory(LedTypes ledtype);
LedController * SecondLedFactory(LedTypes ledtype);
LedController * ThirdLedFactory(LedTypes ledtype);
LedController * FourthLedFactory(LedTypes ledtype);
LedController * FifthLedFactory(LedTypes ledtype);
LedController * SixthLedFactory(LedTypes ledtype);
public:
static LedFactory& instance();
};

#endif /* APPLICATION_LED_LEDFACTORY_H_ */
```

Source file.

```
/*
 * LedFactory.cpp
 *
 *  Created on: Aug 3, 2016
 *      Author: Dev
 */

 #include <LedFactory.h>
 #include "FirstLed.h"
 #include "SecondLed.h"
 #include "ThirdLed.h"
 #include "FourthLed.h"
 #include "FifthLed.h"
 #include "SixthLed.h"

 LedFactory::LedFactory() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

 }

 LedFactory::~LedFactory() {
    // TODO Auto-generated destructor stub
 }

 LedFactory& LedFactory::instance()
 {
    static LedFactory instance;

    return instance;
 }
 LedController * LedFactory::FirstLedFactory(LedTypes ledtype)
 {
    if(ledtype == (LedTypes)LED1)
    {
       return new FirstLed;
    }
    return NULL;
 }
 LedController * LedFactory::SecondLedFactory(LedTypes ledtype)
 {
    if(ledtype == (LedTypes)LED2)
       return new SecondLed;
    return NULL;
 }

 LedController * LedFactory::ThirdLedFactory(LedTypes ledtype)
 {
    if(ledtype == (LedTypes)LED3)
    {
       return new ThirdLed;
    }
    return NULL;
 }

 LedController * LedFactory::FourthLedFactory(LedTypes ledtype)
 {
    if(ledtype == (LedTypes)LED4)
    {
       return new FourthLed;
    }
    return NULL;
 }


 LedController * LedFactory::FifthLedFactory(LedTypes ledtype)
 {
    if(ledtype == (LedTypes)LED5)
    {
       return new FifthLed;
    }
    return NULL;
 }

 LedController * LedFactory::SixthLedFactory(LedTypes ledtype)
 {
    if(ledtype ==(LedTypes)LED6)
    {
       return new SixthLed;
    }
    return NULL;
 }
```

Should I remove that class for increase the dynamic allocation memory issue ? 
Or how can I fix this class ?

Comment: Your program appears to be crashing. What do your three calls from `main()` do? There is probably an `exit()` or failing `assert()` somewhere (though, the assert should give you a pop up when debugging). It could also be stack corruption causing a function to return the wrong location and exiting `main()`. There's a lot that can be wrong.

Comment: Firstly thanks for response. I am using special framework on my board which Quantum leaps. these 3 functions are calling framwork functions and SYS_vRUN is calling endless loop

Comment: @rjp I could not added my comment here that's why I post a new answer below thanks for help.

Comment: Since that is indeed an infinite loop, and the other possibilities have been ruled out, I would suspect that something is smashing the stack and causing a return from a call to an improper location.

Comment: @rjp I have found a problematic module via assertion ID implementation and I made it disable but still compiling not initiliaze during booting up system. After that config after 4 min later program exit is reached appeared in the console again. But at this time code has not been entered to assertion function handling. So now should I focus to Stack size ? or do you have any suggestion for debugging that issue ? Also this problem can occure because of linker ?

Comment: I would suspect not a stack size issue, but perhaps a buffer overflowing somewhere, or, if you are using dynamic memory allocation, a malloc failure that isn't being caught.

Comment: @rjp Yes I am using dynamic memory allocation as new and delete functions in C++ in other modules for keep spaces for other modules. Should I switch to static memory instead of dynamic memory ? Is there any way to catch buffer overflowing issue ?. and I did not use any security function for MCU (illegal memory acces detection , Ram guard etc.)

Comment: C++ is out of my wheelhouse, so I'm not sure how you check your heap allocations there. As for buffer overflows, I don't have a good method other than to just check the likely places (anywhere where you're moving data into a buffer).

Comment: @rjp thanks for the support. But the end of status can we say problem is about the stack or heap problem ?

Comment: I can't say that definitively without debugging myself, but that's where I would look.

Comment: @rjp after your idea I have added the most dynamic memory allocation proccesess class to first question. Should I remove facroty pattern class from my code for increase memoey allocation issue  ?

Comment: @rjp I can share my code either it is not a problem by the way.

Comment: Unfortunately, I already have a job.

Comment: @rjp Thanks a alot ı will focus which we are discussed about till now. And I will report status.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problem has been solved. Main reason was the dynamic memory allocation processes which is used at the factory class.

Comment: This answer is not helping anyone else with a similar problem. If you don't provide more Information then this answer is quite useless for others and it would be better to delete the complete question.